# Highlighting a numeric field from results fetched from custom “_all” fields

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-highlight

I am new to Elasticsearch. We have certain data in different data-types that we want to index and retrieve. We are using custom "_all" fields as explained in the below link

[Custom "_all" fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-all-field.html#custom-all-fields)

Following is our code

For Creating Index

```
PUT myindex
{
  "mappings": {
    "mytype": {
      "properties": {
        "first_name": {
          "type":    "text",
          "copy_to": "contact_details" 
        },
        "mobile_number": {
          "type":    "long",
          "copy_to": "contact_details" 
        },
        "contact_details": {
          "type":    "text"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

For Adding to Index

```
PUT myindex/mytype/1
{
  "first_name": "John",
  "mobile_number": 9988776655
}
```

For Search

```
GET myindex/_search
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "9988776655",
      "fields": [
        "contact_details"
      ],
      "fuzziness": "auto"
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "require_field_match": false,
    "pre_tags": [
      "<tag1>"
    ],
    "post_tags": [
      "</tag1>"
    ],
    "fields": {
      "first_name": {},
      "mobile_number": {}
    }
  }
}
```

Using the above query we are able to fetch results but are not able to highlight the original field value as explained in the following link

[Highlighting Original Fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-all-field.html#all-highlight-fields)

Need to know if we are doing anything wrong or is there a bug

Please note that we have to use the Custom "_all" field as it is important to our requirement. Also, the datatype of the fields cannot be changed.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I've tested your query and it appears to me to highlight the original field, in this case mobile_number with tag fields surrounding it.

Here are the results I get:

```
    {
  "took" : 93,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "max_score" : 0.2876821,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "my_so_index",
        "_type" : "mytype",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 0.2876821,
        "_source" : {
          "first_name" : "John",
          "mobile_number" : 9988776655
        },
        "highlight" : {
          "mobile_number" : [
            "<tag1>9988776655</tag1>"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I'm running the above query on version 6.6 of ElasticSearch. For version 5 the documentation shows a slightly different structure, can you try this:

```
GET myindex/_search
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "9988776655",
      "fields": [
        "contact_details"
      ],
      "fuzziness": "auto"
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "pre_tags": [
      "<tag1>"
    ],
    "post_tags": [
      "</tag1>"
    ],
    "fields": {
      "first_name": {"require_field_match": false},
      "mobile_number": {"require_field_match": false}
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @whatapalaver, May I know which version of elasticsearch you are using. I am getting following result '{
"took": 14,
"timed_out": false,
"_shards": {
"total": 5,
"successful": 5,
"skipped": 0,
"failed": 0
},
"hits": {
"total": 1,
"max_score": 1,
"hits": [
{
"_index": "myindex",
"_type": "mytype",
"_id": "1",
"_score": 1,
"_source": {
"first_name": "John",
"mobile_number": 9988776655
}
}
]
}
}'

Comment: I'm using elasticsearch 6.6 so that presumably accounts for the difference. The version 5 documentation shows the require_field_match: false against each highlight field. I'll edit my answer with a proposal to try. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.0/mapping-all-field.html#all-highlight-fields